# Differences between dart web ui and dart polymer

Tags: dart, polymer

Is there any comparisionlist between `dart web ui` and `dart polymer`? Different syntax, different possibilites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer.dart is basically just a new name for Web UI.

Web UI was always attempting to implement the new web standards and MDV, as was the Polymer project. There are two main benefits to directly porting Polymer and its polyfills to Dart:

1. It's easier to make sure the implementation is complete and compatible. Any small changes in syntax or features that Polymer.dart introduces would have had to have been implement in Web UI anyway.
2. The implementation is more focused on runtime features, rather than compile-time, so it greatly reduces the need for a build step during development. That's a huge win, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some informations on [the original post introducing polymer.dart](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/6laXXxRtA7k/Ms0q3EIMt9MJ).